# Pass login details from one site to another by action post method

Tags: html, post, authentication

I want to use the login information from one site and then post it through a action=login page of another.

Below is my form that the user will be using to login. Then it should post the value to another login site

```
<div class="t_login">
  <h1>Login to your account</h1>
  <form method="post" action="http://www.thissite.com/portal/admin/verifylogin">
    <p><input class="t_input" type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
    <p><input class="t_input" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p class="remember_me">
      <label>
        <input class="t_input" type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
        Remember me
      </label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

But all i get back is that login page of that site.

Thank you

Comment: So if I put my login details to this site, you could potentially log me into any other site?

Comment: If you want to authenticate multiple services using one identity, that's definitely not the way to go. This smells like some fraudulent attempt to steel data.

Comment: That's why we use AntiForgeryToken (or similar)...to prevent CSRF stuff. Then, unless they designed their website really bad, answer is **you can not**.

Comment: Without knowing how the script on the receiving website works, it's impossible to say. It could be blocking external referrers from posting, and just dumps attempts back at the form.

Comment: So for example i make a login form that post login details to facebook then this wouldnt direct me to there logged in page?

Comment: Too explain further is just a quick login form where user doesnt have to click on a link to go to the login page. Is just a quicker way to login

Comment: Let me repeat: **you can NOT**. Any decent website will reject that request. It's called _CSRF attack_ and so _common_ and well-known that even many web-frameworks have in-built protections.

Comment: I just check that the website it self didnt store any token when i visit there home page or login page. So why is it still rejecting my request?

Comment: I don't know about your website but any half decent anti CSRF attack will **at least** use cookie and/or hidden form field plus checks for referrer and origin. Even assuming website you need to post to is very poor designed it'll at least check HTTP referrer and (presumably) HTTP origin (referrer is not but origin is mandatory - AFAIK - for HTTPS) and they'll be inserted by browser in the HTTP request. To summarize: unless website you're trying to work with is terribly designed then there is **nothing** you can do (fortunately!!!) unless you also hack browser...

Comment: Thanks Adriano Repetti